# How can I convert videos with VLC media player?

Tags: video, conversion, vlc-media-player

I use [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) 1.1.4, and I want to convert any video files with VLC media player.

Comment: Have you tried handbrake? It usually gives me better quality output than VLC does.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use Microsoft Excel, but I don't use it to browse the Internet!

Try [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) (they share codecs).

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://win.downloadatoz.com/tutorial/2696,how-to-convert-videos-with-vlc-media-player.html):

> Step 1: Double click the icon of vlc media player. Makes it running.
>
> Step 2: Click "Media", choose "Convert/Save...", a dialog appears.
>
> Step 3: Click "File", in the pannel of File Selection click "Add", add the vedio you want to be converted. The path of vedio will be in the text box. Click "Convert/Save..."
>
> Step 4: Select the destination your file will be put. In the Setting pannel, select the format you want to convert to. Then click "Start" button.

Comment: this is so simple. i have problem with settings.